# Docker Java Client API Connection Pool

Tags: java, multithreading, docker, client, connection-pooling

im using Docker-client API ( https://github.com/spotify/docker-client ) in EE Platform to manage a bundle of containers on remote machine. Java SE Client running in Docker instance in order to process a work. After Processing is done and get a response from se client, im restarting container ,let it wait 15 seconds in a separate Thread and pause that container after time is up. But there is a problem, when i pause containers in multi threads through DefaultDockerClient or DockerClient. Although im setting connectionpoolsize on 1000, im getting following exception while pausing a worker. i have been debugging for hours for PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager whether its set. and yes. its already set on 1000. But it doesnt work for parallel request ? Does anyone has an idea, why it doesnt work ?

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to invoke request
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
at com.spotify.docker.client.DefaultDockerClient.request(DefaultDockerClient.java:1019)
... 9 more

Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Unable to invoke request
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:287)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:407)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:442)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation$2.call(ClientInvocation.java:477)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid use of BasicClientConnManager: connection still allocated.
Make sure to release the connection before allocating another one.
at org.apache.http.util.Asserts.check(Asserts.java:34)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager.getConnection(BasicClientConnectionManager.java:160)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicClientConnectionManager$1.getConnection(BasicClientConnectionManager.java:142)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:423)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:283)